# What platforms are supported by the Detox framework?

Tags: android, ios, detox

Can we run automation test on iOS and Android physical and virtual devices using the detox framework? Will the same code run for all four platforms?

I am starting with Detox framework set up for both Android and iOS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.